# Are there infinite constructions for partial circulant Hadamard matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, combinatorial-designs, circulant-matrices

I believe that the circulant Hadamard conjecture (that there are no circulant Hadamard matrices of size greater than $4\times4$) is still open.

I also know that examples of $(n/2) \times n$ matrices which are partial Hadamard circulant have been found experimentally for moderate values of $n.$

To clarify, a partial circulant $m(n)\times n$ Hadamard matrix $A$ has entries from $\{-1,+1\}$ and if its first row is $a,$ then its subsequent rows are $T(a),\ldots,T^{m(n)-1}(a)$ where $T$ denotes, say, the left cyclic shift operator and $T^k$ is $T$ composed with itself $k$ times.

Is there a known infinite construction for partial circulant Hadamard matrices? Equivalently does a sequence of $m_k(n_k)\times n_k$ Hadamard matrices exist, where $n_k\rightarrow \infty$ and so does $m_k(n_k)$. Note that $m_k(n_k)=o(n_k)$ is allowed, under this definition.

I am aware of references [arXiv:1201.4021, Armario et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4021) and [arxiv:1003.4003, De Launey and Levin](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4003), which address generic partial Hadamard matrices, as opposed to those that are partial circulant.

**Edit:** To make things explicit, the best results I have found **without the circulant constraint** are the following: For any $\varepsilon>0$ and for $n$ large enough, $t\equiv 0~(mod~4)$ there is a $n\times t$ partial Hadamard matrix if $n\leq \frac{t}{2}-t^{\frac{113}{132}+\varepsilon}.$ Subject to the extended Riemann hypothesis the $\frac{113}{132}$ in the exponent  can be replaced by $\frac{7}{12}.$ This matches computational results, see https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55726/an-optimization-version-of-the-hadamard-problem, that have found $\frac{n}{2}\times n$ partial Hadamard matrices up to $n$ somewhere between 50 and 100.

Comment: I just posed a very similar question but have deleted it after seeing this. It turns out that for $n/2$ by $n$ Hadamard partial circulant matrices with $n=4,8,12,16,20,24,28$  the numbers of these matrices is: $12,40,144,128,80,192,560$. There exist $0$ for $n=32$ but more than $0$ for $n=36$.

Comment: Can you give  a reference for the result you refer to in your Edit?

Comment: @dorothy: do you mean the computational results? It's from a computational stackexchange group . I added the link to the question.

Comment: I meant the part directly following "the best result I have found is the following" where you quote some result when $n\leq \frac{t}{2}-t^{\frac{113}{132}+\varepsilon}$. Is that not to do with Hadamard partial *circulant* matrices after all?

Comment: sorry, to clarify that result is for the *general* partial hadamard matrices.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Could you add the exact reference for this particular result to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r\mbox{-}H(k\times n)$ denote a $k\times n$ partial circulant Hadmard matrix in which a row (and hence all) sums to $r$. It's a known result, see Theroem 9 in [1], that $2\mbox{-}H((p+1)\times 2(p+1))$ exists for any prime power $p$. This is because negacyclic $C$-matrices of order $p+1$ exist. In [2], Paley gave a construction of $C$-matrices using the Legendre symbol $\chi$ of the Galois field GF$(p)$. A variation of this construction leads to a negacyclic form for these Paley matrices, see [3] for details.

[1] $\textit{Circulant partial Hadamard matrices}$ by Craigen, Faucher, Low, and Wares, Lin. Alg. Appl. 439 (2013)

[2] $\textit{On orthogonal matrices}$ by Paley, J. Math. Phys. 12 (1933)

[3] $\textit{Orthogonal matrices with zero diagonal II}$ by Delsarte, Goethals, and Seidel, Can. J. Math., Vol. XXIII No. 5 (1971)

Comment: Thank you. Someone just put much the same answer on math.se. On the off chance you are not the same person, would you be able to explain the construction explicitly?  Ultimately I would like to write computer code to construct these matrices.

Comment: @dorothy I'm the same person! Should I change my se name?

Comment: I don't think it matters, but why not?

Comment: @dorothy the construction in [1] is quite lengthy. if you don't have access to [1] I am able to access a pdf of the paper.

Comment: @kodlu Thank you. Yes I managed to get hold of the paper in the end and it is a little too complicated for me to follow properly. What I am looking for is a nice explicit proof-free construction.